# Extending path name in urls.py

Tags: django, django-urls

Supposed my `views.py` contain multiple views that are meant to go deeper in the url path.

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('<int:table_pk>/order/', views.menu_category_view, name='menu_category_view'),
    path('<str:menu_category>/', views.menu_item_view, name='menu_item_view'),
]
```

The first view has the path generated as `<int:table_pk>/order/`.
If I want the second view to have a path as following `<int:table_pk>/order/<str:menu_category>/`, how should i go about passing the variables (in the view  and/or template) in DRY manner?
What if I have more path levels that need to extend the path above it in this same manner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can work with an [**`include(…)`** clause [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/urls/#include):

```
from django.urls import include

urlpatterns = [
    path('<int:table_pk>/order/', include([
        path('', views.menu_category_view, name='menu_category_view'),
        path('<str:menu_category>/', views.menu_item_view, name='menu_item_view'),
    ]))
]
```

The `path(…)` before the `include(…)` is thus common for both `path(…)`s in the list wrapped in the `include(…)`.

You can thus construct a hierarchy by using `include`s where a `path(…)` can be wrapped in an `include(…)` of another `path(…)`, etc.